# How do you handle in the controller two forms on the same page to do different task and endpoints? What is the if statement format?

Tags: java, html

Two DIFFERENT post request ARE MAPPING ON the SAME page or URL. I trying to make one post request for one button do something and have the other submit button do something different

Ive tried naming the forms and an if statement in the controller using if ( action.equals("b1"))

I tried two separate controllers to handle each submit button

Java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processApproveandProceedForm(@RequestParam int seoId, Model model){
   SEO seoInDB = seoDao.findById(seoId);
   seoInDB.setApproved(true);
   seoDao.save(seoInDB);
   return "redirect:/admin/seo/?seoId=" + seoInDB.getId();

}

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processApproveForm(@RequestParam int partnerId, Model model){
    Partner partnerInDB = partnerDao.findById(partnerId);
    partnerInDB.setApproved(true);
    partnerDao.save(partnerInDB);   
    return "redirect:/admin" + partnerInDB.getId();

}
```

Im setting up a page where you can approve an instance of an object called SEO or Partner. Then when you click approve and proceed the SEO will take you to a page to add Students or if you approve a Partner it will redirect to the home page. All of this is displayed on the home page and I want to handle it from the controller using the name of the form which is b1 and b2.

this is a snippet from my controller and I get an error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'adminController' method 
public java.lang.String org.launchcode.GatewaySEC.controllers.AdminController.processApproveForm(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
to {[/admin],methods=[POST]}: There is already 'adminController' bean method
```

Comment: You can map the method to a new URL via the RequestMapping annotation.  Try setting `@RequestMapping(value = "proceed")` for the `processApproveandProceedForm()` method and it should work.

Comment: No both processes take place on the same page

Answer (score 0):

It revealed that the program had a same method name 'adminController', guess you can change it to something else.